# QODBS and SQL Server query performance

Tags: sql-server, qt, odbc

My application makes about 5 queries per second to a SQL Server database. Each query results in 1500 rows on average. The application is written on C++/QT, database operations are implemented using QODBC driver. I determined that query processing takes about 25 ms, but fetching the result - 800 ms. Here is how code querying the data base looks like

```
QSqlQuery query(db)
query.prepare(queryStr);
query.setForwardOnly(true);
if(query.exec())
{
    while( query.next() )
    {
        int v = query.value(0).toInt();
        .....
    }
}
```

How to optimize result fetching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not directly answer your question as I haven't used QT in years. In the actual ODBC API you can often speed up the retrieval of rows by setting SQL_ATTR_ROW_ARRAY_SIZE to N then each call to SQLFetch returns N rows at once. I took a look at SqlQuery in qt and could not see a way to do this but it may be something you could look in to with QT or simply write to the ODBC API directly. You can find an example at [Preparing to Return Multiple Rows](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/c/odbc-tutorial-fetching-results.html#rmr)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just implemented that stuff using native API and got 15 ms! I'm going to try to set the parameter you've mentioned

Comment: Setting SQL_ATTR_ROW_ARRAY_SIZE > 1 will require more memory but should be faster. Don't forget the allocate more space for N rows of data and Indicators passed to SQLBindCol.